# Read-only HFS+ on Windows 10 with boot camp driver question

Tags: bootcamp, windows, dual-boot, hfs+

I've been searching around on the internet for a while trying to answer this question, but I can't get a clear answer for it.

**Background info:**
I'm running El Capitan with a Windows 10 partition on my MBP that I created through Boot Camp. When I ran the boot camp assistant, I made sure the "Download latest support software from apple" box was checked. After that my computer rebooted and I installed Windows onto the newly created partition from a USB drive. I then booted into Windows, where an Installer for the Boot Camp Windows Software popped up. I installed it.

I've read on the internet that the Boot Camp Support Software allows read-only access to the Macintosh HFS+ partition, BUT windows does not recognize the partition, I can't even read from it. Why is this? Is what I read wrong? Or is there a different thing I need to install that's not the software apple put on my Windows Install USB? Or is this feature simply not supported in Windows 10?

I can't figure out why this drive is not accessible to me even though a bunch of places on the internet say that support is included in the Boot Camp Support Software, which I'm fairly sure I installed

**EDIT**: I realize that there are other third party options to get both read and write support for HFS+, but I am specifically looking for an option built in by Apple.

Comment: I installed the support software that Bootcamp Assistant downloaded and I got read-only access to my Macintosh partition. However, I did need to assign the partition a letter via the Disk Management utility in Windows.

Comment: I looked into that but my disk management software doesn't allow me assign a letter to the drive, it doesn't even recognize it. Maybe I should try reinstalling the software.

Comment: Out of interest, was it on windows 10?

Comment: Yes, it was on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved it!

This literally took hours out of my day, but I now know what the problem was. It turned out that the drivers actually were installed. by verified this checking for the presence of the following files:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\AppleHFS.sys
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\AppleMNT.sys
```

The reason that the drive was unreadable is because they **were encrypted with FileVault**. I disabled FileVault in OS X, and when I booted into Windows again, the partition was mounted.

There might be a way to use FileVault and Boot Camp together, I'm not sure. I read in a few places, however, that if you enable FileVault *after* installing Windows with Boot Camp, you can have your drive encrypted and accessible from windows. *(This is just a hunch however, I'll have to look into it more)*

Comment: This did not help me, I don't use FileVault.