# Windows can't see "Macintosh HD" under Boot Camp

Tags: hard-drive, windows, bootcamp, partition, core-storage

I bought a new iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, 2017, with macOS High Sierra 10.13.5) and used Boot Camp to install Windows 10 on it.  The Boot Camp drivers seem to have been installed successfully, and most things seem to work, but I am unable to access the Mac partition from Windows.

According to [what I have read](https://www.howtogeek.com/189250/how-to-share-files-between-mac-os-x-and-windows-with-boot-camp/), the Boot Camp drivers are supposed to have a read-only driver for HFS+, but "Macintosh HD" does not show up for me.

I've read that [FileVault could be the problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213241/read-only-hfs-on-windows-10-with-boot-camp-driver-question), but I double-checked, and FileVault is not enabled.

Then I read that the problem might be because of something called [Core Storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167874/why-i-can-not-see-mac-partition-under-windows-installed-with-bootcamp).  So I tried to follow [these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167868/cant-make-more-than-two-partitions) to revert the partition.  However, that only works if `Revertible` is `Yes`, and in my case, it is `No`.

```
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 9C641579-4351-491E-923A-B2DA1CF80C12
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         724916166656 B (724.9 GB)
    Free Space:   81920 B (81.9 KB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 123FF2CC-8363-4551-AEF2-535FAABDA521
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     27551166464 B (27.6 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 52D21296-80AE-4BC8-BA5F-583E65C62B42
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     697365000192 B (697.4 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 9619CA26-4D92-43F6-AC54-3E10E7F774A0
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume CF6F0197-EDB6-4DC3-B3C4-C22A3DC99D2C
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          724000440320 B (724.0 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

How can I access the Mac partition from Windows?

---

**Additional information:** Here is the result of running `diskutil info /`:

```
   Device Identifier:        disk2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E632

   Volume Name:              Macintosh HD
   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /

   Content (IOContent):      Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                  Journal size 81920 KB at offset 0x183df000
   Owners:                   Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:      Yes
   Booter Disk:              disk0s3
   Recovery Disk:            disk0s3
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI-Express
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              F7E21D0B-FE27-3F1E-AF88-6B86912A95F6
   Disk / Partition UUID:    CF6F0197-EDB6-4DC3-B3C4-C22A3DC99D2C

   Disk Size:                724.0 GB (724000440320 Bytes) (exactly 1414063360 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        4096 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:       724.0 GB (724000440320 Bytes) (exactly 1414063360 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:        29.6 GB (29556273152 Bytes) (exactly 57727096 512-Byte-Units) (4.1%)
   Volume Free Space:        694.4 GB (694444167168 Bytes) (exactly 1356336264 512-Byte-Units) (95.9%)
   Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No

   Device Location:          Internal
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              Yes
   Virtual:                  Yes
   Hardware AES Support:     No

   This disk is a Core Storage Logical Volume (LV).  Core Storage Information:
   LV UUID:                  CF6F0197-EDB6-4DC3-B3C4-C22A3DC99D2C
   LVF UUID:                 9619CA26-4D92-43F6-AC54-3E10E7F774A0
   LVG UUID:                 9C641579-4351-491E-923A-B2DA1CF80C12
   PV UUID (disk):           123FF2CC-8363-4551-AEF2-535FAABDA521 (disk1s2)
   PV UUID (disk):           52D21296-80AE-4BC8-BA5F-583E65C62B42 (disk0s2)
   Fusion Drive:             Yes
   Encrypted:                No
```

And here are a couple of screenshots from Disk Utility:

[image: Disk Utility]
[image: Disk Utility]

Additionally, here is the Windows version:

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, your OSX partition is using `HFS+` and not `APFS` ? The content hint says it uses `HFS+`, but still wondering. `APFS` is not directly readable, one needs to use a driver provided by `Paragon Software`

Comment: @JeanRostan I don't know; how do I find out?  I bought it about a week ago, and I haven't intentionally changed anything about the file system, other than using Boot Camp to partition it.

Comment: Use this `diskutil info /` and look under `type` or just use graphical disk utility inside utilities folder under your apps

Comment: @JeanRostan It looks like HFS+ to me.  I've updated the original question with this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Windows 10 from an ISO that was released after the Anniversary Update was released, then this is normal. The HFS+ drivers that are made by Apple do not work on the Anniversary Update and later.

Comment: It's whatever Microsoft is selling on their website right now.  According to the Settings application it is "Version 1803", whatever that means.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Anniversary update was 1604, so it will probably not work on your installation.

Comment: Does any other vendor make HFS+ drivers that will work on the current version of Windows?  Or will I still have a problem with "Core Storage" even with third-party drivers?

Comment: I can't give much information because I never used one, but you can try Paragon's driver or Transmac's software (NOT driver). Neither of them is free but they have trials.

Comment: I checked Paragon's website, and it said their driver does not work with Fusion Drive.  Since my Mac has Fusion Drive, it looks like I can't use the Paragon driver.